# What is the reason behing Tuples instead of HList in akka-http

Tags: refactoring, akka, generic-programming

As I can see in recent releases of [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala.html), successor of [spray](http://spray.io/), [spray-routing](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/)'s approach of using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) was replaced in favor of self-included [`Tuple`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/util/Tuple.scala)

What is the motivation for this transformation? Has this done just for self-inclusion or pure `Tuples` without [intermediate generic transformations  to HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/tuples.scala) are practically more efficient or simple?

Comment: I'm not sure anybody here is able to answer this question.  Have you tried asking the maintainers of the package in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://gitter.im/akka/dev, Konrad Malawski writes:

> It's about
>
> 1. the horrible error messages that one gets if things go wrong with HLists
> 2. not depending on shapeless, so people can use whatever version of shapeless that they want to
>
>    it's totally possible to build a HList based version of those methods and give it to people as a library, would be fun if someone would maintain it
> 3. we needed a javadsl, so we'd have to build the tuple style anyway